# Cannot write or read serial port using Laird USB dongle - Python

Tags: python, serial-port

I cannot read or write data to the serial port using

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM4', 115200, timeout=0.5, parity=serial.PARITY_EVEN, rtscts=1)  # open  serial port
print(ser.portstr)       # check which port was really used
ser.write(str.encode("hello"))    # write a string
data = ser.readline()          # read line from serial
print(data.decode('utf-8'))     # print line / decoded
ser.close()             # close port
```

I am using a Laird USB dongle which is a bluetooth USB adapter, right now it just stores a program that prints"Hello".

The output only returns "COM 4", I am expecting to see "Hello" also in the output.

I'm unsure if this is code related or could it be a hardware issue? Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: how do you know it can understand this information? Some tools may need to use special protocols to understand information.

Comment: using `Laird USB python` in Google  I found https://github.com/LairdCP/BT510-Python/blob/master/dongle.py and it seems it use `"AT protocol"` to communicate with this device.

Comment: USB dongles and Bluetooth are the means to connect, not the device with which you are communicating. You will not receive any data without connecting any device. If you want to receive what you write yourself, your USB dongle or Bluetooth must have a loopback feature and have it enabled.